# installing firefox Extension using third party installer

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can i insert some firefox extension using windows installer , without adding it manually from firefox add-on manager ,

as I'm trying to make a cross browser toolbar

Comment: How to create path of signed package (unlisted) while making window installer? So that when i install .exe package ,extension should be in path from where it can be directly installed in Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900024/3791822

> You can use the command line for that: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions or the registry: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry

via command line:

```
"C:\program files\firefox\firefox.exe" -install-global-extension "<path-to-extension>\extname.xpi"
```